# Value getting overriden in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

There is a problem in the below code. Can anybody please check the image and code. The values are not getting displayed as per the order of calling instead, it is overridden. the response in the dev tools console is correct bu the UI is showing different resullt. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFI72.png)

Code line for the same -
JS code -

```
$scope.fetchOneBlog = function (id) {
        $http.get(urlBase+'/blog/'+id)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.blogDetailsError=false;
            $scope.blogs = data;
        });
    };

  $scope.getOneUser = function (userId) {       
        $http.get(urlBase+'/user/'+userId)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.blogDetailsError=false;                          
            $scope.oneUser={"name":""};
            $scope.oneUser = data;
            console.log($scope.oneUser.name);
        var myObject = JSON.stringify($scope.oneUser);
            console.log(myObject);

        });
```

There is one more code at the end of the controller js -

```
$scope.init = function(id){
        $scope.fetchOneBlog(id);    
    };
```

Is the above code giving any issue with the view in the below  ?
View code -

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="comment" ng-repeat="review in blogs.review | orderBy: '-creationTime' ">
        <div class="clearfix">
        <h5 class="pull-left" ng-init="getOneUser(review.userId)"><b>{{oneUser.name}}</b></h5>
        <p class="pull-right"><em>Commented on : &nbsp;{{ review.creationTime | date:'medium' }}</em></p>
        </div>
         <p>
        <em>{{ review.comments }}</em>
    </p>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Can anyone please have a look at the image and let me know the problem or mistake.

Comment: Please setup fiddle or plnkr so that we can help.

Comment: What is the expected result? You only show us what result you're getting but we don't know what result you expect to get.

Comment: You can see the image. The names are not same as per the responses in  the console and in the view. As the the image provided you can see that two of the  user's who commented name is Aisha and Kiran which displyed in the console but view doesn't shows correct response. This is the problem.  The name should come in the correct order as per the response which is not happening.

Comment: @hva.narola setting fiddle or plunkr is not possible as the values are been fetched from various sources. Anything missing then please let me know.

Comment: Hi Harshit

It will help if you can also add the getOneUser function as well as fetchOneBlog function.  Also please add more of the HTML snippet.  Also when is the get being called, is it wrapped in another function?

Comment: @OliverMoolman have added the changes. The html code is inside controller that has the js methods defined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that the $scope.oneUser object is going to be overridden each time.  The reason that the console is displaying correctly is because the value is correct at the time of logging.  The value is being overridden is because the value is not in the same context as the repeat item(review) but is in the same context as it's parent blogs.review.

Try something like this:

```
  var isNull = function(obj) {
    if (typeof(obj) === "undefined" || obj === null || obj === "null") {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

$scope.allUsers = [];

  $scope.getUsername = function(userId) {
    var userName = "";

    var users = $scope.allUsers.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.userId === userId;
    });
    //check if the user is in the list and get the first value
    if (!isNull(users) && users.length > 0)
    {
      userName = users[0].name;
    }
    return userName;

  };

  $scope.getOneUser = function(userId) {
    $http.get(urlBase + '/user/' + userId)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.blogDetailsError = false;
        var oneUser = {
          "name": ""
        };
        oneUser = data;
        oneUser.userId = userId;
        $scope.allUsers.push(oneUser);
        console.log($scope.oneUser.name);
        var myObject = JSON.stringify($scope.oneUser);
        console.log(myObject);

      });
```

Then you can use this in the html

```
<h5 class="pull-left" ng-init="getOneUser(review.userId)"><b>{{getUsername(review.userId)}}</b></h5>
```

Let me know if that helps.

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HaQ0z7qY98IIgqhwL9K0?p=preview)

Comment: Nothing is displayed for user name. In the presentation / view it is blank.

Comment: I've created a plunker with this done:

Please have a look
https://plnkr.co/edit/HaQ0z7qY98IIgqhwL9K0?p=preview

Comment: Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(users));` at line number 38 in your script.js . There the user.name value is empty coming in my code. That is why nothing is coming up the screen.

Comment: There is a connection with getUser in your code. Where as I am taking data from an http call and there is no connection with any data related item and so it is storing only the ids being sent in the method `getUsername()` and is not the name as yours.

Comment: Freshly comment these line and you will get the situation what I  am getting except the data what I am fetching using http is correctly coming. `getUser()` method and lines 57 and 58 and add `console.log(JSON.stringify(users));` at line 37 you will get the the same output at the console what I am getting. Just have a look.

Comment: Hi Harshit, I know that the code is not exactly the same as yours, it is just an example to show you that you can get the usernames from a list that you keep instead of overwriting the oneUser object, and this will resolve your problem, please have a look at the output in the plunker to see that it is displaying the expected usernames for each comment.  Obviously you will need to adapt this to fit your code.  I added the comment and I am getting users that match to the comment as expected.  Please adapt it to fit your code and see if that resolves your issue.  Regards Oliver